# Transversality condition with unbounded value function

Tags: boundary-value-problem, optimal-control, dynamic-programming

Consider the following cake eating problem:
\begin{align}
&v(x_0) = \max_{\{u(t)\}_{t \geq 0}}\int_0^\infty{e^{-rt}\ln(u(t))dt}\\
\text{s.t.} \quad &\dot x(t) = -u(t)\\
&u(t) \in [0,x(t)]\\
&x(0) = x_0 > 0\\
&x(t) \in X = [0,x_0].
\end{align}
The value function $v(x) = (\ln(rx)-1)/r$ solves the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation
\begin{align}
rv(x) = \max_{u \geq 0}\{\ln(u) - v'(x)u\}
\end{align}
and yields linear feedback control $\mu(x) = rx$. 
Note that the set of **feasible** states $X = [0,x_0]$ includes zero (clearly one can eat the entire cake).
For $\mu(x) = rx$ being optimal the following transverality condition needs to hold: 
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{-rt}v(x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in X.
\end{align}

> Question: Since $v(0)$ is not defined, I suspect that the transversality condition is violated at $x = 0$. Is $\mu(x) = rx$ optimal? How do I prove it?

**Workaround:**
Since the payoff function $\ln(u)$ is not defined for $u = 0$ we may restrict the set of control functions such that $(u(t),x(t)) > (0,0)$ for all $t \geq 0$.

Define the set of **admissable** control paths 
\begin{align}
U = \left\{u : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R_{++} ~\bigg|~ x(t) = x_0 - \int_0^t{u(s)ds} > 0 ~ \forall t \geq 0\right\}.
\end{align}
Then $x(t) \in (0,x_0]$ for all $t \geq 0$ and $u(\cdot) \in U$ and the transversality is satisfied on the space of admissable states.
Then we may say that $u(t) = rx(t)$ is optimal for all admissable $u(\cdot) \in U$.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking what takes the place of an initial condition on $v(0)$?

Comment: since $x_0=0$ your control must be 0 and the functional diverges. Therefore $x_0$ must be strictly larger than 0. With linear control you will have $x(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. So, you will never eat the entire cake :)